# Почему 0 <= 0 возвращает false?

Tags: javascript

Почему card <= 0 возвращает false? 
    var count = 0;

```
function cc(card) {
  switch(card){
      case 2:
      case 3:
      case 4:
      case 5:
      case 6:
      count ++;
      break;
      case 10:
      case "J":
      case "Q":
      case "K":
      case "A":
      count --;
      break;
  }
      if (card <= 0){
        return count + " Hold";
      } else {
        return count + " Bet";
      }
}

cc(2); cc(3); cc(7); cc('K'); cc('A');
```

Comment: функция возвращает 0 Bet, почему не 0 Hold?

Comment: `if (count <= 0) {` - тщательнее надо

Comment: Может вы определитесь с реализацией, а не на каждую будете создавать вопрос?

Comment: Спасибо большое. MedvedevDev , больше вопросов не будет.